# Paperclip returning a url for non existing styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've added paperclip styles to my Rails model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_attached_file :media,
                :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"}
end
```

New assets that are uploaded have the appropriate thumb style and this returns the correct url:

```
asset = Asset.last
asset.media(:thumb) = correct_url
```

But it seems as though even styles that don't exist return a url:

```
asset = Asset.last
asset.media(:foobar) = some_url
```

I'm adding new styles to my model such as "large" and if that style doesn't exist for previously saved model instances, i'd expect it to return an error or an empty string.

If a style doesn't exist for an instance, how can get paperclip to return an empty string?

```
asset = Asset.last #doesn't have style foobar
asset.media(:foobar) = ''   #or could return an error
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what exactly you want.

If you want to get an error/empty string when requesting an url for JUST WRONG style (i.e. developer misspell it), then you can try following.

By default it just replace tags as you specified in `has_attached_file`. See [interpolate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb) method.

Looks like it is possible to change this default behavior with options. You'll need to implement similar class to `Paperclip::Interpolations`.  See `self.default_options` [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb). `:interpolator` is the one for you.

On the other hand, if you want to get empty url for missing style for particular attachment (i.e. correct, but file not exists for some reason - maybe you've just add new style), then:

I guess this could hit performance (i.e. working with filesystems or even external service). So, not a good idea for generic usage.

You probably should consider run rake tasks when add new style. Paperclip already have `rake paperclip:missing_styles` ([on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake)) to do this. But this might be very long running task (E.g. my hosting server kills rake process before completion).

And again you can make your own interpolator if performance is not an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your second case is what I want. I've added a new style. If I ask for the url path for that style, but that style doesn't exist for that particular attachment, why am I getting a url path?

Comment: So, as wrote in my answer - this is default implementation of paperclip. You can override this with you own interpolator like in first case.

Answer (score 0):

> If a style doesn't exist for an instance, how can get paperclip to
>   return an empty string?

In that simple case, setting `:default_url` to `""` should work:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :media, :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"}, :default_url => ""
end
```

Comment: I guess I'm just surprised that it returns anything. If I add new styles I don't want previously saved attachments to return anything when a style that doesn't exist for that attachment is asked for.

Comment: If I'm correct, :default_url works if attachment is missing at all (i.e. you have no picture assigned to model). So, have nothing to do with missing styles.

Answer (score 0):

I did not think :default_url would handle that scenario, I'll have to check. But what I've done for your case when I really need to know if a style exists is something like the following:

```
flavor = (Faraday.head(post.photo.url(:output)).status == 200) ? :output : :original
url = post.photo.url(flavor)
```

It downloads the file which you take a hit for so keep that in mind. This also assumes you don't want to reprocess all your existing attachments with the paperclip rake task.